# It is possible to get the list of all MySQL system functions?

Tags: mysql

I looking something like:

```
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS
```

to get list of all available system functions for the current server version. It is posible to get the table like [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) directly from the MySQL engine?

Thanks!

Comment: No, not html... just list of functions with description.

Comment: I don't think its possible through command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've got the help tables installed (most binary distributions do; there's a script called `fill_help_tables.sql` if not), you can type:

```
mysql> HELP FUNCTIONS
You asked for help about help category: "Functions"
For more information, type 'help <item>', where <item> is one of the following
topics:
       PROCEDURE ANALYSE
categories:
   Bit Functions
   Comparison operators
   Control flow functions
   Date and Time Functions
   Encryption Functions
   Information Functions
   Logical operators
   Miscellaneous Functions
   Numeric Functions
   String Functions
```

...and then something like:

```
mysql> HELP String Functions
You asked for help about help category: "String Functions"
For more information, type 'help <item>', where <item> is one of the following
topics:
  ASCII
  BIN
  BINARY OPERATOR
  BIT_LENGTH
  CAST
  CHAR FUNCTION
...
```

...before finally doing something like:

```
mysql> HELP bin
Name: 'BIN'
Description:
Syntax:
BIN(N)

Returns a string representation of the binary value of N, where N is a
....
```

**How to generate your own list!**

The following query (on the `mysql` database) gives all functions and their category in a single list:

```
SELECT help_category.name, help_topic.name 
FROM help_topic JOIN help_category 
    ON help_category.help_category_id = help_topic.help_category_id 
WHERE help_category.help_category_id IN (
    SELECT help_category_id FROM help_category 
    WHERE parent_category_id=37
) ORDER BY 1;
```

If you want the text description for each, just add `description` as a column in the `SELECT` clause, although it's long, so you might want to use `\G` instead of `;`

Comment: @Julian MariaDB does a lot of things differently to MySQL. Try `HELP string_functions`