# Possible to get a listing of MySQL system functions from a query

Tags: mysql

To get the UDF's in MySQL I can query the information schema. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA='avails' AND ROUTINE_TYPE='FUNCTION'
```

Is there a similar way to pull the system/global functions, such as `ABS(...)`, from query?

Seems it's not available in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but possibly another database that isn't installed by default? [It is possible to get the list of all MySQL system functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13516656/651174)

Comment: I believe [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516656/it-is-possible-to-get-the-list-of-all-mysql-system-functions) answers your question if I understood correctly. Here are some commands: `SHOW FUNCTION STATUS`, `HELP FUNCTIONS`, `HELP String Functions` etc.

Comment: @roccobaroccoSC right I mean from a straight query though, not a stored procedure or pseudo-one.

Comment: I've seen this request before a few times over the years, but I've never understood why one would need this. Can you describe the scenario for which you need it? Is it because you're trying to develop a turnkey application that must degrade gracefully depending on the version of MySQL?

Comment: Actually, for query parsing on an external mysql client, to see if there may be functions that our application isn't aware of (and future-proofing...)

Comment: @David542: The topic from the link deals with MySQL internal functions if I understood it correctly, not stored functions.

Comment: Is it not easier to just read the reference documentation to make sure you've accounted for all the builtin functions? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/built-in-function-reference.html